# Grails Entity Relationship

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-orm

I have the following entities Alert and Location in Grails. But I cant seem to add the location to the alert_location table. The error is missing method exception. Pls help.

```
class Alerts { 


    static hasMany = [locations:Locations,users:Users]
    Date alertDateTime
    String pest
    String crop


    static constraints = {
        alertDateTime (blank:false)
        pest (blank:false)
        crop (blank:false)
    }

class Locations {


  static hasMany = [ farms:Farms, reports:Reports, reportMessages:ReportMessages]

    String locationName
    String locationXY

    static constraints = {

        locationName (blank:false)
        locationXY (blank:false, unique:true)
    }
}
```

In my code,

```
    Locations loc = new Locations();
    loc.locationName = 'a'
    loc.locationXY = 'aa'
    loc.save()
    Alerts a = new Alerts()
    Date d = new Date()
    a.alertDateTime =d
    a.crop ="o"
    a.pest ="c"
    //a.save()
    println loc.locationName
  loc.addToAlerts(a)
    a.save()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `a.addToLocations(loc)` instead because you are using `a.save()`. Otherwise do `loc.save()`